# how to NOT have calibre reduce pictures' resolution when converting from epub (or anything I guess) to MOBI

Tags: epub, calibre, conversion, mobi, kdp

I'm selling art ebooks on KDP Amazon, and I need the pictures not be shrinked as they automatically are when passing from odt to mobi/epub.
But it would be easier if Amazon didn't have to convert epub itself, time-wise to begin with, and also since there are errors here and there (rarely but still) and it just can't do it sometimes. A hussle.
Now, I'm forced to make epub from libreoffice, then correct it a bit sometime with sigil, then provide it to Amazon. Too time-consuming.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that this is where paid for products make life easier e.g. InDesign

Comment: If I recall correctly the user agreement for using Calibre does not allow for converting so you can sell, only for personal use.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to:

Preferences->Preferences->Common Options->Page Setup

you can set the `Output Profile` to `Tablet`. The Profile description reads:

> Intended for generic tablet devices, does no resizing of images [Screen size: unlimited]